# sound in my app

Tags: iphone

how can I use sound In my application

Comment: you use the singleton class for controling the sound

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your question is very broad, all I can do is refer you to Apple's [Multimedia Programming Guide: Using Audio](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html). There's also a [Getting Started with Video & Audio guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GS_AudioVideo_iPhone/index.html). Last but not least, there are [sample apps](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/index.html?section=Resource+Types&topic=Sample+C#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Sample%20Code) provided by Apple. If you still have trouble ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `AVAudioPlayer` from the AVFoundation-framework on iPhone.

Just

1. Add the AVFoundation.framework to your project
2. Import the AVAudioPlayer to your header-file

   ```
   #import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>
   ```
3. Play a sound like this:

   ```
   NSString *fileName = @"file";
   NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:@"mp3"];
   AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
   initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath] error:nil];
   ```